# How to drop columns from dataframe having all values equal to False(Boolean)?

Tags: pandas, ipython, dataframe

My dataframe has 5 columns with all False Boolean Values. Is there any way to drop all 5 of them in one command?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,False,False,False,False,False],\
                  [2,False,False,False,False,False]])
print df
   0      1      2      3      4      5
0  2  False  False  False  False  False
1  2  False  False  False  False  False

df = df.ix[:,(df != 0).any(axis=0)]
print df
   0
0  2
1  2
```

`(df != 0).any(axis=0)` indicates which columns have False elements